# How to use SharedPreferences to change view visibility in login and logout

Tags: android

How to create `SharedPreferences` with set visibility in login if the user is successfully login the button will be logout and the login will be gone

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    private static String url_check_login = "";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    Context cont=this;
    EditText uname, pword;
    Boolean nega = false;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_user);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);

        Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final int id = v.getId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.btnLogin:
                    new SubmitLogin().execute();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnRegister:
                    Intent i = new Intent (this, Registration.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                    break;
                // even more buttons here
            }
        }



    class SubmitLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging In ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pword.getText().toString()));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_login, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    nega = false;
                    SharedPreferences prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", uname.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent gotoLogs = new Intent(cont, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(gotoLogs);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    nega = true;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (nega) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(cont)
                        .setTitle("Login Failed")
                        .setMessage("Wrong Username or Password")
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                //Close current activity
                startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to set `gone` visibility to button if there is no login info in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: I'm trying to create a login button and logout button with sharedpreferences and setvisibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place info into `SharedPreferences` you should write following:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERNCES_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString(PREFERENCES_LOGIN, login).apply();
```

Variables `PREFERNCES_FILE` and `PREFERENCES_LOGIN` should be defined as `String`:

```
public static final String PREFERNCES_FILE = "my_preferences_file";
public static final String PREFERENCES_LOGIN = "login";
```

On logout there should be:

```
sp.edit().remove(PREFERENCES_LOGIN).apply();
```

Then to check if there is allready some info call:

```
boolean isLogged = sp.contains(PREFERENCES_LOGIN);
```

Then just set needed visibility:

```
login.setVisibility(isLogged ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, here is example. This code should be in `onCreate`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERNCES_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isLogged = sp.contains(PREFERENCES_LOGIN);
Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
login.setVisibility(isLogged ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
login.setOnClickListener(this);
Button logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
logout.setVisibility(isLogged ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
logout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And there should be button in your `login_user` xml with `btnLogout` id.
In `onClick` should be:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btnLogin:
                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERNCES_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                sp.edit().putString(PREFERENCES_LOGIN, login).apply();
                findViewById(R.id.btnLogin).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.btnLogout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //another actions after login
                break;
            case R.id.btnLogout:
                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREFERNCES_FILE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                sp.edit().remove(PREFERENCES_LOGIN).apply();
                findViewById(R.id.btnLogin).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.btnLogout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //another actions after logout
                break;
            // even more buttons here
        }
    }
```

In `login` variable should be login data - I don't know where you should get it.

Comment: `PREFERNCES_FILE` and `PREFERENCES_LOGIN` is variables that you should define by yourself.

Comment: public void onLogOutclicked(View v) {
        isLogged = false;

        loginbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logoutbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
how can i put sharedpreference in this code?

Comment: login.setVisibility(isLogged ? View.GONE, View.VISIBLE);
why is it error in comma?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. `login.setVisibility(isLogged ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE)`